# How to execute adb shell monkey in specified time?

Tags: android, adb, monkey

I want to run monkey in 10 minutes, But monkey only specify the `COUNT`.
I tried the args `--throttle`, but it didn't work. For example,

```
adb shell monkey --throttle 100 -p com.android.email -v 200
```

It execute finished in 5 seconds, but it should be at least `100 * 200 = 20000 miliseconds = 20 seconds`
How to execute adb shell monkey in specified time?
Or execute adb shell monkey as long as possible but not specify `COUNT` a very large number

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue, and after searching, I found that you may need change the order of parameters like this:

```
adb shell monkey -v --throttle 100 -p com.android.email 200
```

it works for me

Answer (score 0):

monkey works by running a script which gets generated according to the parameters that you provide.

Thus providing throttle and count parameters ends up producing a script that takes the appropriate length of time to run on the device, but the adb command itself will complete much quicker.  I think this is what you are seeing.